# #error running igv **Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again

Tags: java, ubuntu

I already looked in previous questions since it appears that my issue is quite common. However I still cannot solve this problem.
When I run the IGV program I got this error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/broad/igv/ui/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

I checked java versions:

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"    
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1056-b12)    
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b12, mixed mode)    

javac -version
javac 1.8.0_152-release    

which java    
/home/sche/anaconda2/bin/java
```

If I understand correctly I needed to install a  uptdated version  of java (e.g. 11):
so I tried:

```
sudo apt update    
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

however, still there is the old version

```
 java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"    
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1056-b12)     
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b12, mixed mode)

javac -version    
javac 1.8.0_152-release
```

I also tried manually with:

```
curl -O https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk11/9/GPL/openjdk-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz    
tar zxvf openjdk-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz    
sudo mv jdk-11* /usr/local/    
sudo vim /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk-11.0.2
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

I really don't understand how to solve this issue
thanks for your help

Comment: Change `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin` to `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` - the path is search left to right. Putting the entry on the right means every other path is searched first (including the old version of Java).

Comment: If you are using ide such as Eclipse or other, you can select jdk from "Installed JREs" menu.

Comment: i changed to export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH but it does not solve (base)   ~$javac -version
javac 1.8.0_152-release
~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1056-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b12, mixed mode)
~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
Nothing to configure.

Answer (score 1):

solved it with

```
set JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/"
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I did:

```
    update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/" 3
    update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/" 3

sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/           3         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   1111      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1

sudo update-alternatives --config javac
There is only one alternative in link group javac (providing /usr/bin/javac): /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
Nothing to configure.
```

Still the same error "Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it by specifying the version of Java that should be used by IGV (v11, not v1.8). You'll have to locate your Java 11 installation first.

```
export JAVA_HOME="/path/to/openjdk-11.0.13-h87a67e3_0"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
igv
```

This code was saved as `runigv.sh`. To run IGV:

```
bash runigv.sh
```

It's a bit of a workaround, so maybe there are more elegant solutions.